# Функция array_rand() в PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет. Решил попробовать написать бота. Нужно чтобы бот отвечал `Да` или `Нет`.

Мой код:

```
$input = array("Да", "Нет");
$random_key = array_rand($input);
```

Вместо `Да` или `Нет`, бот присылает просто 1. Подскажите решение.

Answer (score 2):

Функция [array_rand()](http://www.php.su/functions/?array-rand) возвращает ключ, соответствующий случайному значению

То есть тут вы получаете ключ случайного значения:

```
$random_key = array_rand($input);
```

А само значение можно получить например так:

```
$random_value = $input[$random_key];
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно через array_flip, дабы не создавать много переменных:

```php
$input = array("Да", "Нет");
$random_key = array_rand(array_flip($input), 1);
```

Ещё более удобный и простой вариант предложенный Девочкой с глазами ребёнка ))

```php
$input = array("Да", "Нет");
$random_key = $input[array_rand($input)];
```

Comment: Лучше `$random_key = $input[array_rand($input)];`

Comment: @девочка с глазами ребёнка Тоже отличный вариант. Даже лучше, не меняя ключи со значениями.  Добавьте ответ - я свой удалю )

Comment: да не стоит, лучше дополните свой ответ.